# What material (sealant) to use on fasteners on steel roof

Tags: repair, roof, steel, sealant

Some screws/fasteners have started to leak on my garage steel roof. It’s a large roof (22’x60’). I need to seal all the fasteners…and there are a lot ! The previous owner used the screws on both the ridge and valley of the steel sheets.

I need to seal all of them because I’m not certain which one are leaking.

I saw a “tool” on YouTube that looks pretty good. I think it is called Roof Tube. It basically holds the sealant in a tube. At the end of the tube is a ball bearing that, when pressed against the fastener, lets out a blob of sealant.

This tool looks great for speed and controlling the amount of product used.

The only problem is that nowhere is it documented about what product to use.

Has anyone used such a tool and if so, what sealant did you use?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually you would buy a size larger of metal roof screws and replace the old screws. Look in your roof's technical literature, and you'll likely find this suggestion. Here's some goof suggesting a maintenance cycle of every 5-10 years, https://www.billraganroofing.com/blog/does-metal-roof-require-maintenance. That sounds excessive.

Comment: There are roofing screws with rubber gasket

Comment: Lol on the replacing the screws every 5 to 10 years. Can you imagine! I’m guessing I have over 1000 screws on my roof. I read another article that says you need to inspect the twice a year. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I used the screws with rubber gasket. The metal gasket will prevent you from making a dent, when screwing too hard.

[image: screws]

In addition I used some Tar in tube and filled the hole before inserting the screw. It lasted now over 30 Years with no leaks.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I really want to avoid replacing every screw. There are probably over 1000 of them. I also can’t determine which ones are leaking because the roof is inclosed inside. (Ya, I know that creates another issue about mold and other damage, but that isn’t something I can get into due to cost and time)

Comment: do it once and do it right and you do not have to worry about, unles you want to wait to find out where it is leaking